# How much better Power Within spell gets with each level of upgraded Pyromancy Flame?

Tags: dark-souls

I found the pyromancy spell Power Within to be very useful for increasing dealt damage. I wonder how much Pyromancy Flame casting item upgrades increase its power. Info I found on various wikis is incomplete and only lists the basics.

Answer (score 5):

Power Within does not increase with upgrades for pyromancy flame. There is **literally no way** to make Power Within more powerful. PWI adds +40% damage to all output.

Pre-1.05 patch Upgrading the Pyromancy Glove would actually increase the damage done to the player, leading many people who used PWI to **never upgrade their glove** because it was only detrimental. This has been addressed and if you are fully patched, ***The level of your glove has absolutely no effect on Power Within.***